# Magnetic field path on a surface with axial symmetry

Tags: magnetic-fields

$\newcommand{\dv}[2]{\frac{\mathrm{d} #1}{\mathrm{d}#2}}$
I'm trying to find the path a magnetic field line takes along an axially symmetric magnetic surface.

I'm given:
 - $r,z$ points along a poloidal contour (ie a slice at one toroidal position)
 - $B_r$, $B_z$, $B_\phi$ at each one of these points
 - the number of times it must wrap around poloidally for each time it goes around toroidally
 - It wraps back onto itself (ie the last point is the first point)

So basically I need the $\phi$ points for each one of these $r,z$ points. So I know that $$\dv{r}{z}= \frac{B_r}{B_z}$$, but how would that work for phi because $\dv{\phi}{r}$ does not equal $\frac{B_\phi}{B_r}$.

Answer (score 0):

The answer for small $\mbox{d}r$ and $\mbox{d}\phi$ is to use
\begin{equation}
\frac{r\mbox{d}\phi}{\mbox{d}r} = \frac{B_\phi}{B_r}
\end{equation}